# how to open html template by javascript function in django

Tags: javascript, html, django

I am new to django. I want to open an html page named "addstylist.html" located in the project's templates folder. I want to implement a certain condition on a button click. If that certain condition is true only then I want to navigate a user to "addstylist.html" otherwise stay on the same page. My button function is working fine but I am unable to navigate to that page. Overall my navbar anchor tags are navigating properly. But I am confused what file path of addstylist.html to give exactly in the js file which is in my static folder.

I have configured urls.py, views.py and settings.py for static and templates files.
HTML FILE

`

```
 <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Password1">Enter Admin code</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="Password1" >
                      
            </div>
               
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer justify-content-center" >
              {% comment %} goes to href="addstylist.html" {% endcomment %}
              <button class="LogInBtn" id="LogInBtn">LogIn</button>
            </div>
          </form>
```

`validateadmin.js`

```
document.getElementById("LogInBtn").onclick = function () { 
    var code = document.getElementById("Password1").value; 
    
    //check empty password field 
    if(code == "") {  
        alert("**Fill the password please!");  
        return false;  
     }  
    else if(code == "famu") {  
        alert("Admin logging...");  
        window.location.assign("addstylist.html")
     } 
    
     else{  
    alert("Code is not validated. We can't log you in :(");
```

`

urls.py

`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from pages import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("about", views.about, name="about"),
    path("services", views.services, name="services"),
    path("contact", views.contact, name="contact"),
    path("addstylist", views.addstylist, name="addstylist"),
]
```

`
views.py

`

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
from .models import AdminPanel

def index(request):
    admin = AdminPanel()
    admin.code = "famu"
    return render(request, "index.html", {'admin': admin}) 


def about(request):
    return render(request, "about.html")


def services(request):
    return render(request, "services.html")


def contact(request):
    return render(request, "contact.html")
# button click pages 
def addstylist(request):
    return render(request, "addstylist.html")
```

`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to navigate user to the new page named addstylist.html after validating a condition if the certain conditions are met then user can view the page. I have tried using this line of code :  window.location.href = "addstylist" but it is not navigating though the alerts inside if conditons are running just fine. Alfter showing the alert "admin loggin in" it still remains on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

your code should be like:

```
document.getElementById("LogInBtn").onclick = function () { 
var code = document.getElementById("Password1").value; 

//check empty password field 
if(code == "") {  
    alert("**Fill the password please!");  
    return false;  
 }  
else if(code == "famu") {  
    alert("Admin logging...");  
    window.location.href = "addstylist"
 } 

 else{  
alert("Code is not validated. We can't log you in :(");
```

try above updated code.
you just need to redirect the location href to new href if condition meets like this below like works:

```
window.location.href = "addstylist"
```

Or provide path with app url.

Comment: I tried your updated code. The issue still remains the same. It is not navigating.

Comment: please show both project and app urls